# Unable to change title of button iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

This is my first question here. So, be lenient with me. Actually I am trying to change the text of button. By text, I mean, what is shown on the button. I am using `setTitle("title", for: .normal)`. But it does not seem to work. Actually, I am sending a value back to a scene using callback. I am successfully getting the value back (checked through debugging), but I am unable to set the value as title of the button. Let me know if I need to provide something extra for the question to be answered. Here's the code I am using

```
temp.callback = {
            message in
            var msg = (sender as! UIButton).titleLabel?.text
            msg?.append("=")
            msg?.append(message)
            self.btnManya.setTitle(msg, for: .normal)
        }
@IBAction func btnEnterClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let value = Int(tfEdit.text!)
    if(value! >= from && value! <= to)
    {
        callback?(tfEdit.text!)
        self.dismiss(animated:  true, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
        tfEdit.text = ""
    }
}
```

The problem is, I am not able to change just the text of the button. The other functions like hiding the button and disabling it works fine. I have tried changing the text of the button in viewWillAppear as well. Tried changing the button's text on some other button's action as well. Can anybody confirm that I am supposed to use setTitle to change the text? A sample program where button's text is changed would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You need to post some code so people can help you.

Comment: I have added the code. I am not sure how much code is required to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Where are you executing temp.callback()???

Comment: You probably should execute the setTitle line on main thread.

Comment: @ReinierMelian does that matter? It's executing on a separate scene and returning a value. The value is being returned properly.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq tried that one already. doesn't work.

Comment: Your code only modifies the title for state normal. If you have set a title for other states, you must set these titles, too. Put a `NSLog` with the new title in the last line of your callback.

Comment: @AbuBakarSohail can you post the code where you are executing temp.callback()?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have added the code in the post. Please check.

Comment: @macmoonshine NSLog shows that the button's title is changed for normal state. What is the default state for button? Am I missing some state while changing the button's text?

Comment: The _default_ state is `.normal`. You should print the current state, too.

Comment: @macmoonshine I wrote `NSLog(String(describing: self.btnManya.state))` and it gave `UIControlState(rawValue: 0)`. What does that mean?

Comment: Your button is in normal state. Could you post a small demo project?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help. It seems the problem was caused due to my inexperience. I was trying to change attributed title of the button with a simple string. Guess I needed an attributed string for an attributed title. The problem is solved now. Thanks again.